# Determine if value exists in JavaScript "hash table"

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, hash

I have built a JavaScript object that functions as a hash table.

```
var hashTable = {};
```

The table consists of key value pairs that are manually built. The table will be used to generate a new value based on an old value, or key, in the table.

```
//hashTable['old_value'] = new_value;
hashTable['115004568543'] = 115004567503;
hashTable['115004545983'] = 360000857366;
hashTable['115004723526'] = 360000865566;
hashTable['115004723646'] = 360000865566;
```

I have another variable that is compared to the keys in the hash table. If it matches a key in the hash table, then it can be used to capture the new value mapped to it.

For example, let's say some_value is declared.

```
some_value = '115004568543';
```

Since it matches a key value (or old_value) in the hash table, I can get the new value by calling

```
var new_value = hashTable[some_value];
// new_value is going to be equal to 115004567503 due to the mapping above
```

My problem is that I have two different hash tables that "some_value" is being compared against. I want to see if the first value in the hash is present either in the first hash table OR in the second hash table. So I have been working with:

```
var hashTable = {};
hashTable['115004568543'] = 115004567503;
hashTable['115004545983'] = 360000857366;

var hashTable2 = {};
hashTable2['115004702483'] = 360000857366;
hashTable2['115004560766'] = 360000857366;

var some_value = '115004545983';

if (hashTable.includes(some_value)) {
    var new_value = hashTable[some_value];
    //Do some other stuff with new_value
}

else if (hashTableTwo.includes(some_value)) {
    var new_value = hashTableTwo[some_value];
    //Do some other stuff with new_value
}
```

Additionally, some_value will exist in the first hash table, the second hash table, or not at all. It will not exist multiple times.

**MY QUESTION:** I am trying to use hashTable.includes() to see if some_value is present in either of the two hash tables. It isn't working. What is the best way to determine if some_value is a value in one of the hash tables?

When I try to call hashTable.includes(some_value) I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: hashTable.includes is not a function
```

Comment: What, exactly, is `hashTable`? I'm guessing it's a plain object, not an array? (You also need to use parentheses after an `if`, else you'll get a `SyntaxError`)

Comment: what is `redirect` - how can "calling" `hashTable.includes` produce and error that `redirect.includes` doesn't exist?

Comment: Your question is not clear; Make sure to clarify what is the hashTable, maybe show an example of your implementation

Comment: if your `hashTable` is a plain object, you can use `some_value in hashTable`

Comment: Please clarify when "value" means the value of a hash table key, and when it meanx the value held under the key.

Comment: I cleaned up my question! Thank you all for the feedback. Friday typos were pervasive on the first pass, I apologize that it wasn't clear. I did get an answer as well, thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array.includes()` is an array method. Since your hashtable is based on an object, it doesn't support this method.

If your values aren't falsy (false, undefined, null, 0, NaN) you can use logical [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) to assign the value:

```
var new_value = hashTable[some_value] || hashTableTwo[some_value] || some_value;
```

If they might be falsy, you can use the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) to check if they exist in the object:

```
if (some_value in hashTable) {
    var new_value = hashTable[some_value];
} else if (some_value in hashTableTwo) {
    var new_value = hashTableTwo[some_value];
    //Do some other stuff
}
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much Ori Drori. I definitely learned more about JS too, so I really appreciate it.